# Change height of partial page curl dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, modalviewcontroller, page-curl

Can we change the height of a partial page curl?

e.g. I have some textfield elements on the page and I want to be able to curl the view up half way to show them.

Then when the user clicks into a textfield and the keyboard appears - I want to curl the page up a bit further to show the text field, then curl down again when the keyboard clears.

Is this going to be possible at all? Or do I have to leave a keyboard sized gap at the bottom (kinda pointless).

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start. Can you get the page-curl as a native objective c object and modify it? I can't find any info on it anywhere.

Comment: I can vouch for Thomas. I have had this exact question. I couldn't find anything either. Although, I wanted to control it like on the new Apple Maps App. Where a user could actually control the rate.